# I'm creating an RSS reader and having trouble with feedburner feeds

Tags: javascript, redirect, rss, feedburner, google-feed-api

I'm using the Google Feed API to get feeds and the results contain an link field which is great however a feedburner feed returns something to the effect of google.feedproxy.blahblahblah and I need the actual url for the html.  The google.feedproxy url will redirect.  Is there a way using Javascript for me to get the url that is being redirected to?  Or even just a more elegant way of getting the html url?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the text in <feedburner:origLink>.  it's available in most of the feedburner feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `Accept` header is limited to the RSS and Atom MIME types. If by HTML URL, you mean the site for the feed, look for a `<link rel="alternate"/>` in the feed itself, as its href is the relevant site.